# Why do I get a My Disney window when installing VMware Workstation?

Tags: virus, vmware-workstation

I'm assuming this is a virus, though my virus checker can't find it.

I downloaded the latest VMware Workstation 7 installer. I'm running Windows 7 64bit.

I go to install it, and the installer window is a Disney website.

Upon further investigation, what's happening is that the VMware installer extracts/writes a bunch of files to a temp directory. One of those files is an index.htm file. When I open it, sure enough it's the Disney file.

I used Sysinternals Process Monitor to look for anything fishy, but the only thing I see touching that index.htm file is the VMware installer and explorer.exe

Comment: Did you compare the MD5 or SHA1 checksums with those provided on VMware's download pages? Do they match?

Comment: And where did you download it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot to answer this. It was, in fact, a bug in vmware's installer. The disney index.html file was in my "downloads" directory due to my kid dragging/dropping/saving.

When the vwware installer -- which was in the same directory -- executes, it unpacks its own index.html file into the directory... unless that file already exists. So since there was an unrelated index.html file in there, it did not overwrite it with its own; however, it loaded that index.html file, which caused this behavior.

I reported this bug to vmware, they confirmed, and it's since been fixed.

Bottom line: this was not a virus.

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you have checked this for viruses, but what software did you use to check for viruses? The following are tools that I would use to try to clean the computer:

- [Malwarebytes](http://www.filehippo.com/download_malwarebytes_anti_malware/)
- [Trojan Remover](http://www.simplysup.com/tremover/download.html)
- [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/)
- [Spybot Search and Destroy](http://filehippo.com/download_spybot_search_destroy/)

If you need more help, please let me know!